# Scanning and storing data in PHP using QR code

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i'm working on a project for scanning QR codes for student attendance. Currently i'm able to generate the QR code but scanning the QR code and storing the data of QR code makes me confused. Is there any advice or reference that I could follow? I'm using PHP, WAMP Server, MySQL and CodeIgniter framework. The QR Code library i'm using is from [github code](https://github.com/dwisetiyadi/CodeIgniter-PHP-QR-Code) to generate the QR's.

Comment: what is your exact issue? reading the QR? parsing the contents? using such contents for something? You need to be a bit more specific and provide code showing what you've tried so far and what errors you're encountering. Otherwise, it's next to impossible to provide any helpful insight

Answer (score 0):

Basically, QR code represent a string with certain sequence. What you can do is save an string format in your database and while scanning get the string representation from QR (by converting it to original format) and compare with your db value.